# .strip isn't removing the newline on certain strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, strip

I'm trying to make a basic log-in system, and when I use .strip to remove newline characters (\n) off of two strings read from a file, it works on only one string, even though I use the same thing to remove the newlines from both. Here is my code.

```
def login():
    login_an = input("What is the name of the account you are trying to log in to?: ")
    an_file_name = login_an + ".txt"
    login_passw = input("What is the password to the account?")
    with open(an_file_name,"r") as file:
        account_name = file.readline()
        account_name.strip("\n")
        account_password = file.readline()
        account_password.strip("\n")
login()
```

The `account_name` string is the one that isn't having the newline character at the end removed. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Instead of adding "[answered]" to the title, you should instead accept the answer with the check mark on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.strip()` does not modify the string in-place. It returns a new string with the whitespace removed. Your calls to `.strip()` should look like:

```py
account_name = account_name.strip("\n")
```

rather than

```py
account_name.strip("\n")
```